# Accessing the last element of a Vec or a slice

Tags: vector, rust

I have some code that looks like this:

```
trait Stack {
    fn top(&mut self) -> Option<f64>;
}

impl Stack for Vec<f64> {
    fn top(&mut self) -> Option<f64> {
        match self.pop() {
            None => None,
            Some(v) => {
                self.push(v);
                Some(v)
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut stack: Vec<f64> = Vec::new();
    stack.push(5.3);
    stack.push(2.3);
    stack.push(1.3);

    match stack.top() {
        Some(v) => println!("Top of the stack: {}", v),
        None => println!("The stack is empty"),
    }
}
```

Right now, the `top()` method is modifying `self`, but I think that this should not be necessary. The obvious way to do it didn't really work:

```
fn top(&mut self) -> Option<f64> {
    match self.len() {
        0 => None,
        n => self[n - 1],
    }
}
```

I've toyed around a bit with converting `usize` to `i32` and back, but none of what I'm writing looks as short and readable as I think it should.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

And just after posting the question, the answer appears to be obvious:

```
fn top (&mut self) -> Option<&f64> {
    match self.len() {
        0 => None,
        n => Some(&self[n-1])
    }
}
```

I.e. the `usize` was never the problem - the return type of `top()` was.

Comment: `f64` is `Copy`, so the `&`'s in the return type and the `n` arm of the `match` are not necessary, either.

Comment: Sure wish there was an example of how to use this in context.

Comment: Since the return value of `last()` is defined as `Option<&T>`, `fn top(&self) -> Option<&f64> { self.last() }` suffices.

Answer (score 70):

You can use [`slice::last`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.last):

```
fn top(&mut self) -> Option<f64> {
    self.last().copied()
}
```

[`Option::copied`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.copied) (and [`Option::cloned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.cloned)) can be used to convert from an `Option<&f64>` to an `Option<f64>`, matching the desired function signature.

You can also remove the `mut` from both the implementation and the trait definition.

Comment: btw. if you need a mutable reference, you're looking for [`my_vec.last_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.last_mut)