# How do I return a reference to a concrete type that was added to a vector of trait objects?

Tags: vector, rust

In this code, I take a vector, create a struct instance, and add it to the vector boxed:

```
trait T {}

struct X {}
impl T for X {}

fn add_inst(vec: &mut Vec<Box<T>>) -> &X {
    let x = X {};
    vec.push(Box::new(x));
    // Ugly, unsafe hack I made
    unsafe { std::mem::transmute(&**vec.last().unwrap()) }
}
```

Obviously, it uses `mem::transmute`, which makes me feel it's not the right way to do this. Is this ugly hack the only way to do it?

Additionally, while this compiles in Rust 1.32, it fails in Rust 1.34:

```
error[E0512]: cannot transmute between types of different sizes, or dependently-sized types
  --> src/lib.rs:10:14
   |
10 |     unsafe { std::mem::transmute(&**vec.last().unwrap()) }
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: source type: `&dyn T` (128 bits)
   = note: target type: `&X` (64 bits)
```

Comment: @Shepmaster Strange, it compiles for me on rustc `1.32.0`

Comment: @Shepmaster Well that is pretty much what my code is. I haven't changed anything except the fact that my vector is wrapped in another vector.

Comment: My comment was before you edited your comment to include the version. The version is part of the MCVE; I've edited your question to include the pertinent details.

Comment: You are encouraged to start using `dyn` to denote trait objects: [What does “dyn” mean in a type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50650070/155423)

Comment: I won't have time to answer now, but I'm pretty sure your current code is broken and I don't think there's an easy way without something like [How to get a reference to a concrete type from a trait object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33687447/155423)

Comment: Why do you need to get a reference to the concrete type in the first place? Can you expose the necessary behavior via the trait instead, so that you can simply use the trait object?

Comment: @apemanzilla The actual context is that the `add_inst` function is in an impl for the concrete type and is named `new`. Usually `new` functions return the concrete type.

Comment: *Usually `new` functions return the concrete type* — `new` doesn't *usually* add the returned value to some vector of values or return a reference either. Perhaps you want to rename your function and/or drop returning the concrete type.

Comment: Why not just return as `dyn Trait` ? Why make your life complicated ?

Answer (score 3):

I think that this code is safe:

```
fn add_inst(vec: &mut Vec<Box<dyn T>>) -> &X {
    let x = X {};
    let b = Box::new(x);
    let ptr = &*b as *const X;
    vec.push(b);
    unsafe { &*ptr }
}
```

The trick is to save a raw pointer to `*const X` before converting it to a `Box<dyn T>`. Then you can convert it back to a reference before returning it from the function.
It is safe because a boxed value is never moved, (unless it it moved out of the `Box`, of course), so `ptr` survives the cast of `b` into `Box<dyn T>`.

Comment: Can you point to any guarantees that creating a trait object from a boxed value doesn't move/copy/invalidate the pointer?

Comment: @Shepmaster: I don't have any direct reference that a pointer to a boxed value is not invalidated when casting to a trait object. But from I understand  I expect that to be true from the way boxes and allocators work. My code works also with [pinned boxes](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6bf0054788fed8d5bed5b88dfc01b9c3), which I interpret as evidence that this code is indeed safe.

Comment: @Shepmaster: Reading a bit more, `Box<X>` is converted into `Box<T>` via [`CoerceUnsized`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.CoerceUnsized.html) trait, that has no function members, hence the coercion is done automatically by the compiler, and no reallocation is possible. Also note that this also works with `Rc<T>` and `Arc<T>` and here the object _must not_ be moved.

Comment: I'd certainly *hope* that such a transformation couldn't do anything, but having *extra* certainty with unsafe code is always the right thing, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Your "ugly hack" is actually completely incorrect and unsafe. You were unlucky that Rust 1.32 doesn't report the error, but thankfully Rust 1.34 does.

When you store a boxed value, you create a *thin pointer*. This takes up the platform-native size of an integer (e.g. 32-bit on 32-bit x86, 64-bit on 64-bit x86, etc.):

```
+----------+
| pointer  |
| (0x1000) |
+----------+
```

When you store a boxed trait object, you create a *fat pointer*. This contains the same pointer to the data and a reference to the *vtable*. This pointer is **two** native integers in size:

```
+----------+----------+
| pointer  | vtable   |
| (0x1000) | (0xBEEF) |
+----------+----------+
```

By attempting to perform a transmute from the trait object to the reference, you are losing one of those pointers, but it's **not defined which one**. There's no guarantee which comes first: the data pointer or the vtable.

One solution would use [`std::raw::TraitObject`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/raw/struct.TraitObject.html), but this is unstable because the layout of fat pointers is still up in the air.

The solution I would recommend, which requires no `unsafe` code, is to use `Any`:

```
use std::any::Any;

trait T: Any {}

struct X {}
impl T for X {}

fn add_inst(vec: &mut Vec<Box<dyn T>>) -> &X {
    let x = X {};
    vec.push(Box::new(x));
    let l = vec.last().unwrap();
    Any::downcast_ref(l).unwrap()
}
```

If you couldn't / don't want to use `Any`, [I've been told](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47489449/why-can-comparing-two-seemingly-equal-pointers-with-return-false#comment81937050_47490007) that casting a trait object pointer to a pointer to a concrete type will only keep the data pointer. Unfortunately, I cannot find an official reference for this, which means I can't fully vouch for this code, although it empirically works:

```
fn add_inst(vec: &mut Vec<Box<dyn T>>) -> &X {
    let x = X {};
    vec.push(Box::new(x));
    let last: &dyn T = &**vec.last().unwrap();

    // I copied this code from Stack Overflow without reading
    // it and it may not actually be safe.
    unsafe {
        let trait_obj_ptr = last as *const dyn T;
        let value_ptr = trait_obj_ptr as *const X;
        &*value_ptr
    }
}
```

See also:

- [Why can comparing two seemingly equal pointers with == return false?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47489449/155423)
- [How to get a reference to a concrete type from a trait object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33687447/155423)
- [Accessing the last element of a Vec or a slice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28280035/155423)