# Making a mutable reference to the last value of a vector

Tags: rust

I am trying to obtain a reference to the last value of a vector to simplify referencing it in the following code.

```
fn calculate_errors(&mut self, targets: &[f64]) -> () {r
    let ref mut last_layer = self.vector[self.vector.len() - 1];
    for i in 0..last_layer.len() {
        last_layer[i].error = targets[i] - last_layer[i].value;
    }
}
```

In my attempt here I get the error:

> error[E0502]: cannot borrow `self.vector` as immutable because
>   it is also borrowed as mutable

What would be the proper way to do this? How could I fix this?

Comment: Hi there! I am pretty sure the linked Q&A answers your question. If that's not the case, please let us know and explain why it is not the case. And hint for the next time asking on SO: make sure you have a [MCVE] (this is neither minimal nor complete) and to include the full error message. Thanks!

Comment: See also: [Accessing the last element of a Vec or a slice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28280035/155423); [Get the last element of a vector and push it to the same vector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37579949/155423); [How to clone last element from vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31907887/155423).

Comment: For those coming here from Google: you're probably looking for [`my_vec.last_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.last_mut)